# Black line in end of a iFrame HTML

Tags: html, iframe, tags

I did an IFRAME inside HTML page, and I founded that there is black line in the end of the IFARME, and when clicking inside the iframe the line disapeering.

Here is the black line:

[image: black line example]
<sub>(source: [siz.co.il](http://up385.siz.co.il/up3/hanwjmmy4jzy.png))</sub>

Here is the Code:

**the HTML code that contains the IFRAME tag:**

```
<h2> הזמן עכשיו </h2>
<iframe height="200" src="http://www.****.co.il/book/" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

**the HTML code of the page the IFRAME pointing to:**

```
<HTML>


<head>
</head>


<body>


<div id="bookform">

<form id="form1">

<div style="position: relative; right: 50px">
<p dir="rtl">צ'אק אין:
<input type="text" class="styleCe" id="txtArrival" size="10" tabindex="1" />

<br/>
<br/>

צ'אק אאוט:
<input type="text" class="styleCe" id="txtLeave" size="10" tabindex="2"/></p>
</p>
<br/><br/>


<p dir="rtl"><input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="בדיקת זמינות" alt="בדיקת זמינות"></p>
</div>
</div>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

how i can remove to black line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not part of the HTML, the black line is part of your website's CSS file.

Look through your .css file for it.